# Descargar todos los archivos en carpeta de Google Colab, Download all files in Google Colab folder [answered]

Tags: python, archivo, google-colab

Localizar archivos de google colab en una ruta x y se quiere descargar la todo lo de la carpeta de forma automatica.

Ejemplo

[image: ejemplo archivos 1]

Comment: primera vez usando esta plataforma, no se la forma optima de autoresponder algo :D

Comment: En ese caso lee [ask] y [answer]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ya esta respondido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ejemplo archivo

[image: ejemplo archivo]

usamos google.colab en colab

```
from google.colab import files
```

conocemos la ruta de los archivos

```
/content/ejemplo
```

Si no sabemos la ruta hacemos click derecho sobre la carpeta

[image: ruta archivo]

usamos el siguiente codigo

```
for i in os.listdir('/content/ejemplo/') :  
 #print(i)
 files.download('/content/ejemplo/'+i)
```

[image: resultado]

agregar archivos directos de colab a drive

```
from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd
result.to_csv('example_file.csv')
!cp example_file.csv "/content/drive/My Drive/"
```